# How can I perform a checksum verification in U-Boot before booting?

Tags: checksum, u-boot

I have a TI board booting with u-boot and using a SD card with two partitions one active and one passive(there are other partitions for storing u-boot and persistent settings as well). Whenever there is an update it is downloaded and installed in the passive partition which is then made into the active partition following a reboot.I would like to verify the checksum of the file from the new update before rebooting, which I think needs to be done in u-boot. I tried searching in google but couldn't find helpful resources. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Better than a simple checksum, U-Boot has a CRC32 command.  Of course. the value is calculated over a block of memory, so your file or downloaded image would have to fit in available memory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.